# Website to iphone compatible

Tags: iphone, web

Hii all... I have to work on a website and make it configure to iphone...

I mean like following [this](http://techcrunch.com/) and [this](http://lifehacker.com/)

These website run differently on iphone and different on a normal browser

specially second one which Look like a table view when it run on iphone..

I want to make my website like these....
How to make this

are there any templates to do this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also have a look at some mobile web development client side frameworks like jQTouch.

http://www.jqtouch.com/

As well as iwebkit.net which do a lot of the work for you. In any case they should provide enough sample code to give you a good idea where to start.

Comment: are these for webdesigner or iphone developer?

Comment: these are targeted toward web designers who want to build WebApps for the iphone - or make mobile versions of their existing websites. They deal with web technologies (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Look for `iPhone` in user agent and serve different CSS, views, etc.